# Using TNT4J, TrackingLogger statistics show stats for that class only, what if I want application wide stats?

Tags: java, log4j, tnt4j

Using TNT4J, I have obtained TrackingLogger instances for each class, and now if I try to obtain the logger statistics, it gives me the count pertaining to that class only. What if I want to see the stats for the whole application. If we use a static instance for the whole class. the class name is not printed in the logs. Is there any way to obtain application wide stats along with class names also being printed in the logs?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge TNT4J does not maintain global stats for the whole application, instead only stats per logger instance. In this case you would have to maintain a map/list of logger instances, iterate over the logger instances and collect all the stats. Just make sure to clean the list when logger is no longer needed. You can use weak references.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the latest version addressed this issue. See link: https://github.com/Nastel/TNT4J#logging-statistics for more details.  You can interate over all available logger instances within JVM and request statistics. The only thing is that you would have to add key/value pairs yourself to get totals.